# Why does cmake not find the components of the boost library or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Tags: python, c++, windows, cmake, boost

I have a given random walker implementation.
I'm using Windows 10, usually, I prefer Linux, but for this, I might need my GPU later on and I don't want dual boot on this machine.

The documentation is only this:

> Installation Install from PyPI using pip install rw_noise.
>
> Building The library itself is implemented in C++ and requires a
> modern compiler that supports the C++20 standard. Further, the
> following libraries have to be available:
>
> - Boost (with Python and NumPy support)
> - OpenMP
> - Python3
> - Eigen3
> - Magma, Cuda (optionally, for the GPU solver)
>
> To build the library invoke `python -m build` and then install `pip install <path_to_wheel>` where <path_to_wheel> is likely a file in the
> created dist subfolder with extension .whl.

When trying to run the installation using PyPi, I get a very long error message, though the important part should be the following:

> Could NOT find Boost (missing: python numpy) (found version "1.66.0")

I downloaded the boost binaries from their page and extracted it in various locations at this point hoping that CMake would find it.
I have checked both Python and NumPy are included in this boost version.

I have tried out all the needed dependencies individually they all seem to work as far as I can tell, apart from Magma and Cuda since those are optional I decided to skip them at first and add them later once I know I can get it to work.

I added the boost file as an environment path as "BOOST_ROOT"
I also added the lib folder to the path variable.

Now I have realised that I probably shouldn't be using the binary boost version so I changed it to the normal one
This time I got the following error:

> CMake Warning at
> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-ujbspz4s/overlay/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1398
> (message):
> New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
> targets
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-ujbspz4s/overlay/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1523
> (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-ujbspz4s/overlay/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2134
> (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
> CMakeLists.txt:22 (find_package)
>
> CMake Warning at C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-ujbspz4s/overlay/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1398
> (message):
> New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
> targets
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-ujbspz4s/overlay/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1523
> (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-ujbspz4s/overlay/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2134
> (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
> CMakeLists.txt:22 (find_package)
>
> CMake Error at C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-ujbspz4s/overlay/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230
> (message):
> Could NOT find Boost (missing: python numpy) (found version "1.84.0")
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-ujbspz4s/overlay/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600
> (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
> C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-ujbspz4s/overlay/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2392
> (find_package_handle_standard_args)
> CMakeLists.txt:22 (find_package)

I did check again, and both Python and NumPy are in the boost folder under .../boost_1_84_0/libs/python and .../boost_1_84_0/libs/python/src/numpy

Changing the CMake file should not be the answer, since it is given in the rw_noise git repository and it is made by someone more competent.

I might've forgotten something that I have tried already, I'm just very lost at this point.
If something is missing or you need more information don't hesitate to ask!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have seen someone getting similar error messages, but their fixes all didn't work.

Comment: "Now i have realised i probably shouldnt be using the binary boost version" - No, you should use Boost in **binary** form. For debugging purposes, try to build the project directly with CMake (instead of via `pipi`). When run `cmake`, pass it additional parameter `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON`. That way CMake will print exact locations and exact names of Boost libraries which are searched. Check that on your PC you have those libraries.

Answer (score 1):

As unsatisfying as it is.
I chose to opt for linux and it worked first try in less than 3min.